# Unassigning a login from a user in SQL Azure?

Tags: sql, azure

I can create a user in a database without a login by using the `CREATE USER` command and including `WITHOUT LOGIN`.

Is there a way to remove the link between a user and a login that has already been established? I have tried using the `ALTER USER` commands but without success.

I have considered deleting the user and and then re-creating without a login but that would lose any object permissions that I've set up for the user.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove the login?

```
USE [master]
GO

DROP LOGIN [myuser]
GO
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion but I'd like to keep both the user and login just unlink them if at all possible.